# Dojo versions and Intern compatibility

Tags: javascript, dojo, intern

This should be an easy question for the [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/) and [Intern](http://theintern.io/) gurus our there.

What versions of dojo do the different versions of Intern work with without any core configuration changes required?

For example I had come up against an issue recently where I used [dojo 1.9 with intern 1.7 and had an issue where the default AMD loader that Intern expects was not correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24494698/dojo-1-9-and-intern-1-7-require-on-is-not-defined). Whilst this type of problem can be fixed with some Intern configuration values, it would be good to get a clear understanding of what versions work out of the box (by default) with each other without any core configuration changes like the AMD loader issue for example?

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to install Intern now is [via npm](https://theintern.github.io/intern/#installation). As such, the correct version of each Intern dependency will be fetched and installed for you - including Dojo - so there's no need to manually manage these anymore. Simply run `npm install intern` and you can rest assured the correct version of Dojo will be internally installed and used by Intern.